# How to customise docker-compose containing the odoo app and postgresql with non default database name, user name and password?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, odoo, default

I have an application (odoo, but my question may be for any app, I don't know) and a database with database default name, user and password. All is launched with docker-compose. With these default values, it works great (I have copy/pasted only what is relevant):

```
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    user: root
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
  volumes:
      - ./postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    image: odoo:15
    user: root
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=odoo
  volumes:
      - ./etc:/etc/odoo
      - ./odoo-data:/var/lib/odoo
```

There is also a config file `etc/odoo.conf` which needs to be updated and I did (here the default values):

```
db_name = postgres
db_user = odoo
db_password = odoo
```

If for example I set the password to *123*, the user name to *my* and the database name to *mydb*, remove the containers and suppress `./postgresql` to restart clean, I get the following error from the database host:

```
odoo-db-1   | 2022-09-18 15:08:17.420 UTC [908] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my"
odoo-db-1   | 2022-09-18 15:08:17.420 UTC [908] DETAIL:  Role "my" does not exist.
```

Of course, I have updated both the docker-compose and odoo.conf files with my values.

**What could I miss?** My investigations at this point have failed.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    user: root
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_db
      - POSTGRES_USER_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_password
    restart: always             # run as a service
    volumes:
        - ./postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    secrets:
      - postgresql_user
      - postgresql_password
      - postgresql_db

  web:
    image: odoo:15
    user: root
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "10013:8069"
      - "20013:8072" # live chat
    tty: true
    command: --
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_user
      - PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_password
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:fr
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:fr
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - ./etc:/etc/odoo
      - ./odoo-data:/var/lib/odoo
    secrets:
      - postgresql_user
      - postgresql_password
    restart: always             # run as a service

secrets:
  postgresql_db:
    file: odoo_pg_db
  postgresql_user:
    file: odoo_pg_user
  postgresql_password:
    file: odoo_pg_pass
```

Here is my `etc/odoo.conf`:

```
[options]
addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons
data_dir = /etc/odoo
admin_passwd = "my_own_admin_password"
logfile = /etc/odoo/odoo-server.log
db_name = my_db
db_user = myself
db_password = "my_db_user_password"
dev_mode = reload
```

The `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# set the postgres database host, port, user and password according to the environment
# and pass them as arguments to the odoo process if not present in the config file
: ${HOST:=${DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR:='db'}}
: ${PORT:=${DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT:=5432}}
: ${USER:=${DB_ENV_POSTGRES_USER:=${POSTGRES_USER:='odoo'}}}
: ${PASSWORD:=${DB_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD:=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:='odoo'}}}

# install python packages
pip3 install pip --upgrade
pip3 install -r /etc/odoo/requirements.txt

# sed -i 's|raise werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest(msg)|self.jsonrequest = {}|g' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py

DB_ARGS=()
function check_config() {
    param="$1"
    value="$2"
    if grep -q -E "^\s*\b${param}\b\s*=" "$ODOO_RC" ; then       
        value=$(grep -E "^\s*\b${param}\b\s*=" "$ODOO_RC" |cut -d " " -f3|sed 's/["\n\r]//g')
    fi;
    DB_ARGS+=("--${param}")
    DB_ARGS+=("${value}")
}
check_config "db_host" "$HOST"
check_config "db_port" "$PORT"
check_config "db_user" "$USER"
check_config "db_password" "$PASSWORD"

case "$1" in
    -- | odoo)
        shift
        if [[ "$1" == "scaffold" ]] ; then
            exec odoo "$@"
        else
            wait-for-psql.py ${DB_ARGS[@]} --timeout=30
            exec odoo "$@" "${DB_ARGS[@]}"
        fi
        ;;
    -*)
        wait-for-psql.py ${DB_ARGS[@]} --timeout=30
        exec odoo "$@" "${DB_ARGS[@]}"
        ;;
    *)
        exec "$@"
esac

exit 1
```

And:

```
cat odoo_pg_db
my_db
cat odoo_pg_user
myself
cat odoo_pg_pass
my_db_user_password
```

And my project folder tree:

```
.
├── addons
│   └── readme.md
├── docker-compose.yml
├── entrypoint.sh
├── etc
│   ├── addons
│   │   └── 15.0
│   ├── odoo.conf
│   ├── odoo.conf.meld
│   ├── odoo-server.log
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── sessions
├── odoo-data
├── odoo_pg_db
├── odoo_pg_pass
├── odoo_pg_user
├── postgresql [error opening dir]
├── README.md
├── run.sh
└── screenshots
    ├── odoo-13-apps-screenshot.png
    ├── odoo-13-sales-form.png
    ├── odoo-13-sales-screen.png
    └── odoo-13-welcome-screenshot.png
```

The [odoo:15 dockerfile](https://github.com/odoo/docker/blob/333b10955096da859c7f581935bd243bce743589/15.0/Dockerfile) does not include hard written database name nor user regarding the database, only an app user set to *odoo*, but this is for the web app. It makes use of a config file with the default database name user and password like depicted above,  but I provide the modified one with my values. The docker files makes use of `ENV` to refer to it: `ENV ODOO_RC /etc/odoo/odoo.conf`. Then it runs an [entrypoint](https://github.com/odoo/docker/blob/233277f7be894217ae9c3e781862804beb180fb7/14.0/entrypoint.sh) containing:

```
DB_ARGS=()
function check_config() {
    param="$1"
    value="$2"
    if grep -q -E "^\s*\b${param}\b\s*=" "$ODOO_RC" ; then       
        value=$(grep -E "^\s*\b${param}\b\s*=" "$ODOO_RC" |cut -d " " -f3|sed 's/["\n\r]//g')
    fi;
    DB_ARGS+=("--${param}")
    DB_ARGS+=("${value}")
}
check_config "db_host" "$HOST"
check_config "db_port" "$PORT"
check_config "db_user" "$USER"
check_config "db_password" "$PASSWORD"
```

With these `check_config`, it gets my values from the config file.

The [postgres:14 dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/56a1986772dd0f9488d54dccb82427c0db0b0599/14/bullseye/Dockerfile) contains only the superuser name *postgres* set with a `useradd`.

Note: of course, there is more to be done after this like replace *root* user, use Docker secrets, but that's another topic.

Comment: I can't figure out what you are doing.  Rather than showing the config files you are *not* using and then giving us a narrative about how you changed them, why not just show us the ones you are using?

Comment: Sure, I have updated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `postgresql` folder contents were not suppressed with `sudo rm -fr postgresql/*` while the containers were deleted, since created with the odoo user. I have to do `sudo chmod -R 777 postgresql` before.

Now I can see in the docker console that the environment variables are correctly set. Other problems now, but this one is solved.